# Query asking parameters on menu load

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, menu

I have a form called "frmExpedicao", it's record source is a query called "slcExpedicao" that requires two parameters in order to filter the data, that are taken from fields of form "frmExpedicao" itself. I set the default values to field "flt_dt_entrega" = Date (today) and "op_tp_solicitacao" = 1 ("Pedido"). In order to filter to work, I had to call "Me.Requery" on method "Form_Load" of "frmExpedicao". So far so good, it showing the orders to close today, how I need it. However, when I put this "frmExpedicao" on a tab of a menu, right after login it shows pop-ups of the query "slcExpedicao" asking for the parameters. Probably because the "Form_Load" from "frmExpedicao" hasn't been called yet. Because if I open the "frmExpedicao" first, then the menu, it works fine. Do you know to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

[image: frmExpedicao record ource]
[image: slcExpedicao parameters from frmExpedicao]
[image: requery frmExpedicao on load]
[image: asking parameters on menu load, right after login]
[image: if open frmExpedicao before frmMenu it works properly]

Comment: You could change your query to using [TempVars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tempvars), which you set 1) on application start, before opening the menu (set to default values), 2) on afterupdate on the form.

Comment: Thanks @Andre, it solved!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I declared TempVars on login:

```
TempVars.Add "DataEntrega", Date
TempVars.Add "TipoSolicitacao", "Pedido"
```

And use them as criteria on the query:

```
[TempVars]![DataEntrega]
[TempVars]![TipoSolicitacao]
```

Also update their values and requery if user selected another filter:

```
[TempVars]![DataEntrega] = Me.flt_dt_entrega.Value
Me.Requery

If op_tp_solicitacao = 1 Then
    [TempVars]![TipoSolicitacao] = "Pedido"
Else
    [TempVars]![TipoSolicitacao] = "Amostra"
End If
Me.Requery
```